# Getting input headers in openresty

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I use openresty as nginx server with spnego-http-auth-nginx-module
This module replace request header *Authorization: Negotiate YIIG...* with *Authorization: Basic ...* and set **REMOTE_USER** header.
How to copy original Authorization header value to another custom header key to save original authorization header value?

Answer (score 0):

This config snippet return needed data:

```
   ...
        set_by_lua_block $xauth {
            local inp = ngx.req.raw_header(true)
            return string.match(inp, "Negotiate .*==")
        }
        uwsgi_param XAUTH $xauth;
    ...
```